# Azure Service Bus get response to message

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I am busy researching Azure service bus. I want to use it to replace a system where we use multiple `http post` requests.

However I cannot see how one gets a response to the message which you enqueue?

Am I maybe misunderstanding how service bus is meant to be used? Is it a fire and forget type of message?

Answer (score 1):

Service bus is Advance message queue protocol so yes it's fire and forget. Where you drop the message and interested parties pick them up. It's kind of buffer between services where your messages are queued .

In service bus you have couple of options. You have single queue where each worker is polling to read the message. Another way is called pub-sub (topic-subscription) model. In this model you have topic but can have multiple subscriptions. When you publish the message to topic the interested parties which are subscribed to subscription get the related message.